# Find a number inside a QString

Tags: c++, qt, pattern-matching, qstring

I have a QString with some number inside it, for example

```
first_34.33string
second-23.4string // In this case number is negative
```

How can I extract number from the string?

EDIT:

This function seems to work, using regexp in replies:

```
float getNumberFromQString(const QString &xString)
{
  QRegExp xRegExp("(-?\\d+(?:[\\.,]\\d+(?:e\\d+)?)?)");
  xRegExp.indexIn(xString);
  QStringList xList = xRegExp.capturedTexts();
  if (true == xList.empty())
  {
    return 0.0;
  }  
  return xList.begin()->toFloat();
}
```

Comment: Use QRegExp to define a regular expression matching what you're looking for. They're quite powerful.

Comment: I thought that was interesting question and I found this: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl20a.html You can use it with QRegExp.

Comment: You should not be copying an answer into the question. If you have a better answer, feel free to answer your own question. If you wish, you can comment on answers of others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for valid numbers: `QRegExp("(-?\\d+(?:[\\.,]\\d+(?:e\\d+)?)?)")`

edit: sorry, messed up with the brackets, now it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a simple function for that:

```
static double extractDouble(const QString &s)
{
    QString num;
    foreach(QChar c, s) {
        if (c.isDigit() || c == '.' || c == '-') {
            num.append(c);
        }
    }
    bool ok;
    double ret = num.toDouble(&ok);
    if (ok) {
        return ret;
    } else {
        throw "Cannot extract double value";
    }
}
```

Comment: what if you have a string with first_24.2e23string?

Comment: it works with "-4cas", but it fails with "dweok23.234.asd" (another dot after the number).

Comment: You could sanitize this by counting the dots and require to have a number before and after.